# Go Getter Methods vs Fields, Proper Naming

Tags: go, naming-conventions, getter

In Effective Go, it's [clearly stated](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#Getters) that in the case where a field is unexported (begins with a lower case letter) a getter method should have the same field name but starting with upper case; the example they give is a `owner` as a field and `Owner` as a method. And they explicitly advise against using `Get` in front of the getter method name.

I frequently encounter situations where I need the field to be exported for JSON marshaling, use with an ORM, or other reflection related purposes (IIRC reflect can read but not modify unexported fields), so my field would need to be called `Owner` in the example above and thus cannot have an `Owner` method.

Is there an idiomatic way of naming which addresses this situation?

**EDIT**: Here's a concrete example of what I'm running into:

```
type User struct {
    Username string `db:"username" json:"username"`
    // ...
}

// code in this package needs to do json.Unmarshal(b, &user), etc.
```

.

```
// BUT, I want code in other packages to isolate themselves from
// the specifics of the User struct - they don't know how it's
// implemented, only that it has a Username field.  i.e.
package somethingelse

type User interface {
    Username() string
}

// the rest of the code in this other package works against the
// interface and is not aware of the struct directly - by design,
// because it's important that it can be changed out without
// affecting this code
```

Comment: Just use the "Get" prefix. This is what the [Go protobuf generator](https://github.com/golang/protobuf) does.

Comment: @TimCooper I hear you, but I'd almost rather mangle the field name, since the interface method name will appear in more places (and be used across more packages) and is more important to make intuitive and idiomatic.

Comment: Why use a Getter/Setter at all if the field is exported? That's just making the interface more confusing, by allowing multiple ways to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: See edit - it's not two ways of doing the same thing if you are trying to isolate some parts of the code via interface.  Code that knows about the struct directly uses the field, code that just knows about it via an interface uses the method.

Comment: If all you need is the username then why use an interface at all? Just pass around the username.

Comment: Because behaviors change over time and may involve multiple methods.  In this example the somethingelse package needs a `Username`.  But during the lifetime of the project we might add `HasRole(string)bool` and a few others.  It would not be an exact duplication of all the struct fields - just what it needs to know; but some of them very well might be exactly the same as field names just by coincidence.

Comment: How many different implementations of `User` are you expecting?

Comment: There's one User that I'm providing as a default in a library I'm writing; however developers using the library need to be able to use their own struct if they so desire - thus the need for an interface, for interaction with other parts of the system.  I've also got at minimally 3-4 other objects/structs where this same pattern applies.

Answer (score 15):

Don't use getters and setters if your fields are exported.  This just confuses the interface.

If you need a getter or setter because it does something (validation, formatting, etc), or because you need the struct to satisfy an interface, then don't export the underlying field!

If you need an exported field for the sake of JSON, database access, etc, *and* you need a getter/setter, then use two structs, one exported and one private, and define a custom JSON marshaler (or db access method) on the public one:

```
type jsonFoo struct {
    Owner string `json:"owner"`
}

type Foo struct {
    owner string
}

func (f *Foo) SetOwner(username string) {
    // validate/format username
    f.owner = username
}

func (f *Foo) Owner() string {
    return f.owner
}

func (f *Foo) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(jsonFoo{
        Owner: f.owner,
    })
}
```

Comment: I get the idea and yes this would work but is something I'd like to avoid.  Please see my OP edit for more info on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Interesting - you're right that using two separate structs could might not be too bad.  This is a variation that will handle marshaling without custom code - the struct with the field(s) is embedded in an outer struct that has the method(s): https://play.golang.org/p/l_-PRmmydG

Comment: Using an interface is a good reason to use both structs. You should still use both structs, though, because having both getter/setter and an exported field is still really confusing, and bad design.

Comment: @squirtgun Go has adopted a philosophy of being explicit over being concise. It's one of the things that makes Go so easy to read and learn.

Comment: @Flimzy I realize that. But I am just expressing my opinion and seeing if any others feel the same. I feel like it would actually be easier to read if this wasn't necessary.

Comment: Obviously some people agree with you, since they've designed languages that hide such complexity :)  The people who feel strongly about that generally don't like Go. And that's okay.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to post this as an answer, derived after considering @Flimzy's answer, which makes a lot of sense.

The basic idea is to have one struct with exported fields which can be used for marshaling, and another separate struct which has the sole purpose of providing the methods which meet the needed interface.

This requires no custom marshaling code, and gives a clear meaning to each struct, IMO:

```
type user struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
}

type ExportedUser struct {
    // EDIT: explicitly doing "user *user" instead of just doing "*user"
    // helps avoid confusion between between field names and methods
    user *user
}

func (u ExportedUser) Username() string { return u.user.Username }

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Test: %q", ExportedUser{user: &user{Username: "joe"}}.Username())
}
```

The question of whether it should be `user` or `User` above is a bit unclear to me - since it may make sense for the type to be visible for use in a Go template, e.g. `{{euser.User.SomeOtherField}}` Thus allowing all of the fields to be accessible if needed.  Regardless, the answer above functions the same either way.

Comment: This solution still exports the embedded `Username` field.  Try this:  `x := ExportedUser{user: user{Username: "joe"}}; fmt.Println(x.Username)`. You can solve this by naming `*user` as a field in `ExportedUser` rather than embedding it, as in `type ExportedUser struct { user *user }`

Comment: @Flimzy Valid point - although the code in my example does compile, I guess it would be more clear and explicit to have User only have fields, and ExportedUser only have methods, and exclude any possibility of Go's syntactic sugar (where it translates u.FieldName to u.embeddedStruct.FieldName) causing confusion.

Comment: Sure, your code is valid, so should compile. It just doesn't resolve the concern of exposing the same data via both a getter/setter pattern and an exported variable.  But I think you understand the implications, so now you can make your decision :)