# Go Property Visibility & API Design

Tags: go, visibility

So I have a `LineItem` struct that contains a Price property that needs to be exported for SQLx to set the value from the database but the desired value requires logic to be applied to get the value (e.g. when LineItem.Refunded = true then LineItem.Price = 0.00 even if it's not $0.00 in the DB).

I don't want the property to be manually pulled / adjusted so I want to create a `LineItem.Price()` method that uses the logic to get at the "real" (aka calculated) value.  If I make the `Price` property private now sqlx/JSON can't put the price in the existing `LineItem.price` field.  I saw a [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189126/go-getter-methods-vs-fields-proper-naming) post where the two choices were use a method name like `GetPrice()`and leave the struct property public (`LineItem.Price`) meaning the API consumer would need to know not to use `Price` property and use `GetPrice()` method instead.

The other option being create a separate struct for exported data that gets used for DB & JSON (e.g. `ExportedLineItems`) and a separate struct for the "API" (e.g. `LineItems.price` and `LineItems.Price()`).  Even seeing an example I'm unclear how this would work in this case.  I tried pulling the data with `ExportedLineItems` and then converting it `lineItem := models.LineItem(ExportedLineItem)` but it gives me:

`cannot convert ExportedLineItem (variable of type models.ExportedLineItem) to type models.LineItem`

Leaving the property public and using `GetPrice()` seems like a simple solution but also seems like it goes against proper design by allowing the visibility to be public and the API is less clear (e.g. you have to know not to use `LineItems.Price` directly).  Can anyone provide insight?

Edit:
It's not my favorite but one approach I just tried that does seem to work is pulling the data using `ExportedLineItem` and then manually assigning all properties and using setters for private ones.

```
lineItem := models.LineItem{
    ID:      ExportedLineItem.ID,
    OrderID: ExportedLineItem.ID,
}
lineItem.SetPrice(ExportedLineItem.Price)
```

Comment: Another option would be to have `Price` public, and a `LineItem.CalculatedPrice()` to return the calculated price

Comment: That's actually what I've got now just seems like using `LineItem.Price` directly is both possible and wrong so I was thinking I could use package visibility to make it such that the correct choice was the obvious / only one.